# currency.properties file in JDK7

Tags: java, ubuntu, currency

From this [oracle java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html):

> Suppose that a country adopts a different currency and the ISO 4217
>   maintenance agency releass a currency update. To implement this
>   update and thereby supercede the default currency at runtime, create a
>   properties file named /lib/currency.properties. This file
>   contains the key/value pairs of the ISO 3166 country code, and the ISO
>   4217 currency data. The value part consists of three comma-separated
>   ISO 4217 currency values: an alphabetic code, a numeric code, and a
>   minor unit. Any lines beginning with the hash character (#), are
>   treated as comment lines. For example:
>
> Sample currency property for Canada CA=CAD,124,2

However I cannot create a file `currency.properties` in my `usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/lib` as I am not the owner. I have also tried the command `sudo chmod root .`  but apparently it does not affect it. I am using ubuntu 12.04 and running a Jdk1.7.0.
Is it possible to add that file or those java folders are unchangeable?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off topic? Why would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a file from your app conf dir. Run this code at the start of your app

```
String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
System.setProperty("java.home", "conf");
Currency.getInstance("USD");
System.setProperty("java.home", javaHome);
```

this will make Currency read props from conf/lib/currency.properties

Comment: Actually I tried it out and does not work to my system.